# Jquery how to get text() on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all text on page.  I have tried this without luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Side = $(page).text();
    alert( Side );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'body'` instead of `page`. `page` is not a defined variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Side = $('body').text();
    alert( Side );
});
```

Other options are `document` or `html`, but these would also include non-body text, such as the contents of the `<title>` tags.

If you want to strip out the JavaScript, you can use:

```
var Side = $('body').clone();
Side.find('script').remove(); // Remove <script> elements, etc.
Side = Side.text();
```

If you really want to strip all invisible items, use:

```
Side.find(':hidden').remove(); // instead of the second line
```

Comment: There is also HTML and javascript in the alert.

Comment: Another question how to remove whitespace?

Comment: Consecutive whitespace (including newlines)? `Side = Side.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`. Excluding newlines? `Side = Side.replace(/[ \t]+/g, ' ');`.

Comment: I have used trim() but it does not remove all the whitespace

Comment: @Railsbeginner `$.trim` only removes whitespace at the beginning and end. Have you already used my proposed solution? EDIT: I learned RegExp through practising. If you want to learn RegExps as well, I recommend the [Mozilla Developer Network: Regular expressions guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

To remove html tags, all extra whitespace, and script/style/other tags, try

```
var clone = $('body').clone();
clone.find('script,style,object,link,embed').remove();
var Side = clone.text().replace(/(\s){2,}/g,"").replace(/<\/?[^>]*>/g, "");
```